# How can this Erlang sys.config be decomposed?

Tags: erlang, beagleboneblack, beagleboard, slack

Given an Erlang [sys.config](https://github.com/DonBranson/BeagleBone-Black-Mousetrap/blob/master/config/sys.config) that looks like this:

```
[
    {mousetrap, [
        {slack_user, "mousetrap"},
        {slack_channel, "#mousetrap"},
        {slack_token, "<slack token here>"},
        {pins_export_file, "/sys/class/gpio/export"},
        {pins_root_directory, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio"},
        {pins, [
                {gpio0, 30, "1 (over workshop door)"},
                {gpio0, 31, "2 (by basement freezer)"},
                {gpio1, 16, "3 (in the kitchen pantry)"},
                {gpio0, 5, "4 (Not yet wired)"}
        ]},
        {quiet_minutes, 5},
        {pin_check_interval_seconds, 1}
    ]}
].
```

I'd like to break it out so that the settings for each component are separated within the config file. For example, the pin_library for the BeagleBone really has no reason to include knowledge of the overall mousetrap app, so it makes sense to break it out. Likewise for the notification_library that sends messages to Slack:

```
[
    {mousetrap, [
        {pins, [
                {gpio0, 30, "1 (over workshop door)"},
                {gpio0, 31, "2 (by basement freezer)"},
                {gpio1, 16, "3 (in the kitchen pantry)"},
                {gpio0, 5, "4 (Not yet wired)"}
        ]},
        {quiet_minutes, 5}
    ]},
    {pin_server, [
        {pins_export_file, "/sys/class/gpio/export"},
        {pins_root_directory, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio"},
        {pin_check_interval_seconds, 1}
    ]},
    {notification_library, [
        {slack_user, "mousetrap"},
        {slack_channel, "#mousetrap"},
        {slack_token, "<slack token here>"}
    ]}
].
```

However, this doesn't work because pin_server and notification_library are not apps, which is what this construct requires within sys.config. What would be a proper Erlang way to break out these settings into suitable categories, so that [pin_library.erl](https://github.com/DonBranson/BeagleBone-Black-Mousetrap/blob/master/src/pin_library.erl) could change from using:

```
{ok, PinsRootDirectory} = application:get_env(mousetrap, pins_root_directory),
```

to using

```
{ok, PinsRootDirectory} = application:get_env(pin_server, pins_root_directory),
```

EDIT:

Just to clarify why I think this is important. The components pin_server and notification_library attempt to comply with [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). But when pin_server invokes `application:get_env(mousetrap, pins_root_directory)`, it breaks the wall of SRP because it creates a dependency on a component where it should not have a dependency. That is, on the mousetrap app. Now it cannot be reused in other apps without a code change. Same goes for the notification_library. The pin_server is potentially applicable to any application that wants to interrogate the BBB's pins. The notification_library is useful in any app that wants to send a Slack notification. Neither should reference the mousetrap app, because they shouldn't have any 'knowledge' of that app.

EDIT:

Based on @michael's guidance, I started by breaking out slack notification to a separate OTP Library at https://github.com/DonBranson/slack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Erlang does not in any way control the access between applications and environment within a node (any application can access any other applications environment), I'm not sure what you really gain by this subtle change of use... and in truth, if it is logical that pin_server is clearly and definitely a part of the mousetrap application, I think you should just not try to do this; work with the system as it is supposed to be used instead.

Having said this though, because there is no access control as such, you CAN set environment for applications that don't exist like this:

```
application:set_env(nonexisting, foo, bar).
application:set_env(anotherphantom, bat, baz).
```

But if you run up a node with non existing applications in the sys.config, the configuration for those applications will not be loaded.

#### A hack you could do

You COULD have your application start read your environment and set up the environment of the not-really-existing pin_server application, and unset environment from the mousetrap application, before starting the top level supervisor. This would achieve what you want, but...

I wouldn't recommend this though even though it is possible, as there's obviously some danger the release manager wouldn't spot a conflict if an application of the name you purloined was later introduced.

#### Better alternatives (applications and included applications)

An alternative is to make pin_server an application.

If the only barrier to this is that the proposed pin_server application would not really make any sense at all except in the context of your mousetrap application, then you could make it an 'included application'. Included applications are applications that have their own app file, and are really just like a normal (primary) application, but they are started within the supervision tree of your primary application (see [Included Applications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/included_applications.html)) and would immediately allow you the change of use you want, IF you don't mind creating the extra application.

#### Library applications

Again it's an application, and I don't think this is probably appropriate in your case, but, there is also such a thing as a 'library application', which is an application without servers (you don't need to implement the application callback module, it just becomes a logical grouping for your modules, API and environment). If you create an app file without a `mod` entry, it becomes a library application. The reason I don't think it's probably appropriate is that `pin_server` sounds like a server, and thus should be supervised, but this would also permit you the change of use you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I see is to require any apps that use `pin_server` and `notification_library` to read the environment variables and inject them into the those components when they're initialized.

Comment: Sounds to me like you are advocating what I labelled as a hack in my answer. I really only listed this option for completeness because it directly allows you to accomplish what you want without changing your structure... however given your additional edit about your SRP compliance I'd say more than ever that the right answer is to have pin_server and notification_library as separate (primary) apps. You've clarified they usefully stand alone, so if you make them their own apps any Erlang developer would expect and understand it and you can then just write your sys.config without any messing.

Comment: They're not useful in isolation. They're only useful in conjunction with an app.

Comment: Also, what I'm suggesting is different from what you suggested, in that I would inject the settings rather than set another environment variable.

Comment: You say `The pin_server is potentially applicable to any application` in the current edit of your question, and you say `They're not useful in isolation` in the above comment. This confuses me. In an effort to respond I can only say that Erlang apps need not be a means to their own end necessarily; an Erlang app need not be an application in the every day persons use of the word, it can be just so much useless software without some other Erlang app to use it to do something useful. An Erlang app is just a bit of software with dependency relationships to other Erlang apps.

Comment: Good point. Like inets, for example, as an Erlang app that's useful in a standalone app.

Comment: Yep, or stdlib, kernel, public_key, compiler... Probably only a tiny proportion of Erang apps are those apps that collect together and use other apps and actually constitute what would be considered an application by normal people. If `The pin_server is potentially applicable to any application` then I would actually say under the Erlang app/node/release paradigm I would say it HAS to be an Erlang application or part of an Erlang applicaiton with anything else you like as long as additions do not break your SRP compliance.